# Can't retrieve more then 50 records from Azure MobileServiceClient (Node.js)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, apache, cordova, azure

So I'm building an Apache Cordova app (Android), angularjs based, and using the WindowsAzure MobileServiceClient library to retrieve data from my Easy Table's, created in a SQL Database.

This works! Until I'd like to retrieve more then 50 records.
So I added the .take(100) to my table-read. Still 50 records..
Then I thought, maybe the take function doesn't work at all, so I changed the amount to 5, and I only got 5 records. So the take function is somewhat working, but not above 50 records.

Since it's a node.js backend, how do I increase the pagesize?

Here's my current code:

```
msc.tables.pokemonType = null;
msc.tables.pokemon = null;

msc.init = function () {
    console.log('MobileServiceClient initializing...');

    var mobileServiceClient = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient("https://blablablabla");

    msc.tables.pokemonType = mobileServiceClient.getTable('PokemonType');
    msc.tables.pokemon = mobileServiceClient.getTable('Pokemon');

    console.log('MobileServiceClient initialized!');
}


msc.getAllPokemonTypes = function() {
    console.log('getAllPokemonTypes - called');
    return msc.tables.pokemonType.read().then(function (pokemonTypes) {
        console.log('getAllPokemonTypes - done');
        return pokemonTypes;
    }, msc.handleError);
}

msc.getAllPokemons = function () {
    console.log('getAllPokemons - called');
    return msc.tables.pokemon.take(100).read().then(function (pokemons) {
        console.log('getAllPokemons - done');
        return pokemons;
    }, msc.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the source code of table operations of Mobile Apps in node.js, the [read operation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/blob/master/src/express/tables/operations.js#L9) ultimately receives `context.query` which is a [`queryjs`](https://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/module-queryjs_Query.html) object, which contains a `take()` function which can limit the number of items returned to the specified number.

Additionally, the `take()` function is contained in the mobile app server sdk, so it doesn't work on your client end code.

You can do some modification on your Easy Tables scripts, E.G.

```
table.read(function (context) {
    context.query.take(100);
    return context.execute();
});
```